# PostgreSql Right Join From 3 Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

Registrations

| no_reg | name |
| --- | --- |
| 20210520 | A |
| 20210521 | B |
| 20210522 | C |
| 20210523 | D |
| 20210524 | E |

ICD

| no_icd | no_reg |
| --- | --- |
| A000 | 20210520 |
| A001 | 20210521 |
| A002 | 20210522 |
| A003 | 20210523 |
| A004 | 20210524 |

DTD

| no_dtd | description | no_icd |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DTD0 | DTD A | A000 |
| DTD1 | DTD B | A000 |
| DTD2 | DTD C | A222 |
| DTD3 | DTD D | A333 |
| DTD4 | DTD E | A444 |

I want to join the three tables to obtain this result:

| no_dtd | description | no_icd | no_reg | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DTD0 | DTD A | A000 | 20210520 | A |
| DTD1 | DTD B | A000 | 20210520 | A |
| DTD2 | DTD C | A222 | NULL | NULL |
| DTD3 | DTD D | A333 | NULL | NULL |
| DTD4 | DTD E | A444 | NULL | NULL |

This is my query:

```
SELECT
     dtd.no_dtd,
     dtd.description,
     icd.no_icd,
     registration.no_reg,
     registration.name
 FROM registration
 INNER JOIN icd ON registration.no_reg = icd.no_reg 
 RIGHT JOIN dtd ON icd.no_icd = dtd.no_icd 
 ORDER BY registration.name ASC;
```

But somehow the rows containing NULL are not being shown and I want them to appear.

My query result

| no_dtd | description | no_icd | no_reg | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DTD0 | DTD A | A000 | 20210520 | A |
| DTD1 | DTD B | A000 | 20210520 | A |

Comment: You have to make a left join because you want all items from registration

Comment: Your query does what you want:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f14e576ae3f2e19e89855535110633e.  I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a little [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/be753/3/0) using this data

```
CREATE TABLE REGISTRATIONS (
    no_reg int,
    name VARCHAR (50), 
    PRIMARY KEY(no_reg)
);

CREATE TABLE ICD (
    no_icd VARCHAR(4),
    no_reg int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(no_icd)
);

CREATE TABLE DTD (
    no_dtd VARCHAR(4),
    description VARCHAR ( 50 ),
    no_icd VARCHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(no_dtd)
);


INSERT INTO REGISTRATIONS (no_reg, name) VALUES 
(20210520,  'A'),
(20210521,  'B'),
(20210522,  'C'),
(20210523,  'D'),
(20210524,  'E');

INSERT INTO ICD (no_icd, no_reg) VALUES 
('A000',    20210520),
('A001',    20210521),
('A002',    20210522),
('A003',    20210523),
('A004',    20210524);

INSERT INTO DTD (no_dtd, description, no_icd) VALUES
('DTD0',    'DTD A',    'A000'),
('DTD1',    'DTD B',    'A000'),
('DTD2',    'DTD C',    'A222'),
('DTD3',    'DTD D',    'A333'),
('DTD4',    'DTD E',    'A444');
```

It seems that you want ALL records in DTD table to be shown so this should be the "master" table of the join operations and it should be located at the left.

```
SELECT D.*, I.no_reg, R.name
FROM DTD D 
LEFT JOIN ICD I ON D.no_icd = I.no_icd
LEFT JOIN REGISTRATIONS R ON I.no_reg = R.no_reg;
```

Obtained result

```
no_dtd  description no_icd  no_reg      name
DTD0    DTD A       A000    20210520    A
DTD1    DTD B       A000    20210520    A
DTD2    DTD C       A222    (null)      (null)
DTD3    DTD D       A333    (null)      (null)
DTD4    DTD E       A444    (null)      (null)
```